# Non-inverting amplifiers Offset Nulling

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog

I have a Non-Inverting amplifier with single supply which doesn't have offset-null pins, is there any method for external Offset-Null without the need negative supply.

[image]

Comment: Does your input swing all the way down to zero?

Comment: The input ranges from 2mV-20mV
I added the schematic above

Answer (score 1):

Although small, this opamp has some current flowing into it's inputs, about 300 nA. This causes a voltage drop across the resistor(s) that provide this input current. This opamp has a rail-to-rail input stage consisting of an NPN pair and a PNP pair. Since your input voltage is very low it will be only the PNP pair that does the actual work. So that means that a small current will flow OUT of the inputs ! This current wants to go to ground and it will mostly do so through R13. So 300 nA x 1 kohm = 0.3 mV intrinsic offset !

The positive input does not have any reistors so there will be no additional voltage drop. There's your offset ! You need to add a resistor in series with the + input of the opamp. Yes that goes against what you learned that opamps have zero input current ;-) If you make it a variable resistor you can calibrate out the offset.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the reason for offset compensation? This is important - sometimes - for split supply only. In this case, we want that without any input signal the dc voltage at the opamp is zero (or at least as small as possible). In this case, we could save a coupling capacitor at the output for suppressing the dc portion.

However, in your case (single supply) you have to establish an artificial DC operational point using a suitable DC voltage at the non-inv. input (in addition to any ac signal to be amplified). So - there is no need to take care of any offset voltage.

The same applies if the input signals are not going to negative values (DC only).

Comment: "there is no need to take care of any offset voltage." Yes there is, this is not an AC amplifier ! It has no single operating point, any possible input voltage is it's own operating point. Any DC offset at the input will be seen in combination with the input voltage. Let's say the input voltage is 5 mV, the offset is 1 mV, then the difference between the inputs (V+ - V-) = 1 mV so the voltage at the - input is regulated to 4 mV, meaning the output will be at 404 mV. With no offset it would be 505 mV. A 1 mV offset gives 101 mV error at the output !

Comment: I know what you mean (and I am able to calculate the influence of an offset) - however, how do you know that the amplifier is NOT for ac ? Would you really use a single supply amplifier for a dc input as low as 2mV ?

Comment: Sorry - I forget to complete the last sentence: ...without a suitable dc reference voltage ?

Comment: If the amplifier would be designed for AC I'd expect to see coupling capacitors. Also it is mentioned the input voltage is 2mV - 12 mV. Yes you CAN use some opamps this way (with an input voltage around their neg. supply rail). If the opamp has a rail-to-rail input (which this one has) you can :-) Not all opamps are as limited as the good old 741 or TL07x.